# The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData?'. (Documentation)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I am using a library that requires an icon of type `package:flutter/src/widgets/icon_data.dart` aka `IconData`. I'd like to use my own .png file asset as an icon. I googled for solutions and everybody points out to the usage of `ImageIcon`. However when using this - the following error appears:

```dart
        CircularMenuItem(
            iconColor: GuiColors.textLight,
            color: GuiColors.primary,
            icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icons/sword.png")),
            onTap: () {
              //callback
            }),
```

The error is:

```
The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData?'. (Documentation)
```

Comment: You can't do that because you've used a plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the package that contains `CircularMenuItem` but my guess is `icon` parameter expects `Icon` whereas `ImageIcon` has a return type `ImageIcon`. In this scenerio i don't think you can use your own icon with this package

Comment: I checked and icon is of type `IconData?`. That's why I am so confused

Comment: That's interesting. It appears I used ImageIcon when return type is Icon in BottomNavBarItem, I also dont get why it shouldnt be used there